# Chrome Driver is not getting during npm install

Tags: node.js, selenium, vue.js, npm, selenium-chromedriver

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! chromedriver@2.46.0 install: `node install.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the chromedriver@2.46.0 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-02T18_05_40_924Z-debug.log

I am trying to run an open source code. But it is giving me error!

I have tried to install chromedriver manually and with `npm install chromedriver` but nothing is working for me.

What is the problem I can't find out!!!!

Comment: Have you tried to remove the folder `node_modules` and the file `package-lock.json` from the project folder and doing a new `npm install`? (This is the npm equivalent of "have you tried turning it on and off again")

Comment: Yes. Same problem.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver#force-download

Comment: No. It will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and then installing chromedriver worked for me.

```
npm uninstall chromedriver

npm install chromedriver
```